# Using EventToCommandBehavior with a gesture recognizer

Tags: mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a label which I am using to navigate to another page in my app via a tap. This works fine using the `Tapped` with a `TapGestureRecognizer` but when trying to implement MVVM and move the logic out of the code-behind, I had some trouble getting the `Tapped` event to fire a command on my view model.

I can solve this with the following implementation:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Name}">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource
                AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:HabitsOverviewViewModel}},
                Path=TapCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

However for other events, i.e. `Appearing`, I have successfully used [`EventToCommandBehaviour` from the MVVM tookit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior).

For consistency and readability, I wanted to also use `EventToCommandBehaviour` here, but cannot seem to get it to work. The `TapGestureRecognizer` has no `Behaviours` property, and if I define it under `Label.Behaviours`, `Tapped` is not recognised as a valid event.

Is this functionality available, or is my code just wrong?

This is what I have tried with the `EventToCommandBehavior` in a couple of different places but tapping does nothing (TappedCommand exists in the view model and is successfully trigged in the above implementation):

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Name}">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            EventName="Tapped"
            x:DataType="viewModels:MyViewModel" /> <!-- x:DataType is defined differently in the outer scope as this sits within a collection view -->
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following article: [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.label?view=net-maui-8.0)

A label has no "Tap" or "Tapped" event, therefore you cannot work with EventToCommandBehavior in that way. The right way to use a Tap command is how you did it in the first place.